# Execute bash commands on remote machine using python script

Tags: python, ssh

I have a python script that establishes ssh connected using `os.system()` function :

```
def livestream():
   os.system('ssh -X ubuntu@192.168.0.2')
   os.system('cd Desktop') #doesn't get executed on remote machine
```

I know that `os.system()` executes commands on the same machine.

Further, I need to execute a program present on the remote machine.

My question is how do I execute bash commands in python once ssh connection is established?

Answer (score 2):

```
def livestream():
   os.system('ssh -X ubuntu@192.168.0.2 "cd Desktop"')
```

Comment: I need to manually type the password and then i get this `nehal@nehal-300E4Z-300E5Z-300E7Z:~$ exit
logout
Connection to 192.168.0.2 closed.
sh: 1: cd darknet: not found
sh: 1: ./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolo.cfg final.weights: not found`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `call` method from the `subprocess` module.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html